# How to Split a Large Compressed File in Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-beam

When reading in the initial data for my Apache Beam pipeline, I keep running into OOM errors.   In my use-case, I have a large gzipped file of JSON objects.  The file is very large, and I would like to split it into the individual JSON objects for the output PCollection.  I open the files from a ReadIO source, and incrementally read the data using a GZipInput stream.

My (simplified) DoFn looks like:

```
  class MyFn extends DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String> {
    @ProcessElement public void apply(ProcessContext ctx) {
      try (var is = new GZIPInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(ctx.element().open()))) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
          ctx.output(s.nextLine());
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The challenge with this is that the number of inputs is very small (usually just 1 file),  the number of outputs is very large (millions).  When decompressing and outputting the objects, the Beam runner buffers all the objects in memory, which eventually results in an OOME.

After reading the Beam source code, I can't find a way to pause processing in the middle of handling the input to my `DoFn`.  Because the input is compressed, it would be difficult to pause or resume decompressing.   The initial read of this data is not parallelizeable, but all subsequent stages are.  The output objects aren't time-based, so using Windowing doesn't appear to be appropriate.   Bundles also don't appear to apply, since they seem to be framed around input size, not output size.  (There isn't a method called to say "The DoFn is finished with this bundle".)

What I am looking for is a way to flush the output data in the middle of my `@ProcessElement` function.

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace with your OOM error and a code snippet of your pipeline if it's possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since the OOM stack trace is some random allocation that fails, not the allocation of the line itself.   (i.e. the OOME changes locations each run).   I ran MAT to confirm that the `OutputAndTimeBoundedSplittableProcessElementInvoker.ProcessContext` is the where the data is being held.

Comment: I don't know enough about decompressing to know whether it would work, but the recommended approach for a DoFn with few inputs and many outputs would be to implement it as a [SplittableDoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns). But these usually require the ability to begin processing (i.e. decompressing) a file partway.

Comment: I tried using a RestrictionTracker with two different approaches, but both ended up not panning out.  Since the file is compressed, checkpointing (via SplittableDoFN) is not doable since the split function would need to re-read the already processed part of the file.

Keeping the GZIP decompressor state in the tracker also might be a way to resume, but it needs to be serializable, which GZIPInputStream is not.  (It is itself a deserializer, but the object it not serializable).

Comment: I did some asking around and it sounds like you're on the right track despite the roadblock you're hitting. You'd need to find some way to store the GZIP decompresser state somehow so you could resume decompression after checkpointing. Maybe there's some way to serialize GZIPInputStream I'm unaware of, or alternative GZIP decompressers that support it. An expensive option that would always work is checkpointing at X elements, and then when continuing after the checkpoint is to start decompression again but skip the first X elements.

Comment: There's also workarounds that attempt to avoid the problem entirely. If you can switch to multiple smaller input files instead of one large one that would avoid the OOMs. Alternatively, if you could decompress the file separately then you can write an SDF processing the uncompressed file, which should be much easier to implement checkpointing (It might even already be implemented as part of FileIO).

Comment: Doing the decompression out of band is the solution I ended up going with.  It's a little cumbersome since I can't depend on Beam's temporary file cleanup, but I was able to make progress.